# How to produce list of words from the text file in scala

Tags: scala, word-frequency

I have a text file named shakespeare.txt which contains certain portions of shakespeare novel

```
val list1 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("shakespeare.txt")
  .getLines
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
```

I am expexting the result :

```
list1=(hamlet,the,efficient,...etc)
```

but this code didnt produce the list of word after seperation

Comment: And if you add ".toList" at the end of your expression?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the list like this:

```
scala> val list1 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/anurag/test.txt").getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+")).toList
list1: List[String] = List(Hello, this, is, an, testing, file, Hello2)
```

Thanks.